# Java Regex check previous char before splitting

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

This:string:must~:be:split:when:previous:char:is:not~:this

I need to split the line with the delimiter ":" but only if the character before the delimiter is NOT "~"

I have the following regex now:

```
String[] split = str.split(":(?<!~:)");
```

It works, but since I arrived at it purely by trial and error, I'm not convinced that its the most efficient way of doing it. Also, this function will be repeatedly called on large strings frequently, so performance does come into consideration. What is a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** To make this more fair I wanted to use a compiled Pattern and see the results of that. So I updated the code to use compiled pattern, non-compiled pattern and my custom method.

While this isn't using regex it proves to be faster then the regex given.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":(?<!~:)");
    for (int runs = 0; runs < 4; ++runs) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int index = 0; index < 100000; ++index) {
            "This:string:must~:be:split:when:previous:char:is:not~:this".split(":(?<!~:)");
        }
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Run: " + runs + " Regex: " + (stop - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int index = 0; index < 100000; ++index) {
            pattern.split("This:string:must~:be:split:when:previous:char:is:not~:this");
        }
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Run: " + runs + " Compiled Regex: " + (stop - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int index = 0; index < 100000; ++index) {
            specialSplit("This:string:must~:be:split:when:previous:char:is:not~:this");
        }
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Run: " + runs + " Custom: " + (stop - start));
    }

    for (String s : specialSplit("This:string:must~:be:split:when:previous:char:is:not~:this")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static String[] specialSplit(String text) {
    List<String> stringsAfterSplit = new ArrayList<String>();

    StringBuilder splitString = new StringBuilder();
    char previousChar = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); ++index) {
        char charAtIndex = text.charAt(index);
        if (charAtIndex == ':' && previousChar != '~') {
             stringsAfterSplit.add(splitString.toString());
             splitString.delete(0, splitString.length());
        } else {
                splitString.append(charAtIndex);
        }
            previousChar = charAtIndex;
    }
    if (splitString.length() > 0) {
        stringsAfterSplit.add(splitString.toString());
    }
    return stringsAfterSplit.toArray(new String[stringsAfterSplit.size()]);
}
```

**Output**

```
Run: 0 Regex: 468
Run: 0 Compiled Regex: 365
Run: 0 Custom: 169
Run: 1 Regex: 437
Run: 1 Compiled Regex: 363
Run: 1 Custom: 166
Run: 2 Regex: 445
Run: 2 Compiled Regex: 363
Run: 2 Custom: 167
Run: 3 Regex: 436
Run: 3 Compiled Regex: 361
Run: 3 Custom: 167
This
string
must~:be
split
when
previous
char
is
not~:this
```

Comment: Accepted for the tests and the custom function. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly simpler approach is this:

```
(?<!~):
```

That way you don't match `:` twice. I doubt you'll see any difference in performances though. It is also very simple to write without a regular expression by simply looking for the next colon, and checking for tilde before it.

Comment: I'd have guessed the OP's way was faster: don't do the lookbehind until you know there's a need for it.  You know the lookbehind is going to succeed at almost every position, so it makes sense to filter on the `:` first.  And in my tests, `:(?<!~:)` averages almost twice as fast as `(?<!~):` (but both are ridiculously slow compared to a hand-coded approach).

Comment: @Alan - Very true. I didn't mean matching `:` twice is slow - I referred to the simplicity of the pattern (though I've don't that poorly, it isn't clear at all). As for performance, as always, you should check according to average data - what if the string has a ridicules number of escaped colons? (ok, not a good example, but it can work if the pattern is a bit more complex). Anyway, good point. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan His way is faster when you change my code to use this new approach it is slower, although not by much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
`[^~]:`

Tested in JS

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Java with .split() it eats the character before the split. Please rework before a down vote.

Comment: Just FYI, that won't match ":Anything" which, depending on exactly what OP wants, should be split into "" and "Anything"

Comment: Yep, tested it again and it wont match. I was looking at the split length earlier. Working on an alternative....